# Implementing integration points for custom logic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, integration, custom-component

What is the traditional approach or best practices for integrating custom logic into a web application?  More specifically...  I am currently working on a web application targeted at paperless manufacturing.  The application architecture is as follows:

-Heavy jQuery-less JavaScript front-end using YUI
-Back-end exposed via REST API using Spring Core, Spring MVC, Spring Security
-Integration with external systems (mostly ERPs) via Spring Integration, ActiveMQ
-Currently runs exclusively on Tomcat 7, but ideally needs to be App server independent

Given the nature of manufacturing and the lack of standardization (especially small/middle market companies) almost all of our potential clients need some sort of custom logic to make our application better fit their existing processes.

What I envision looks something like custom classes that would be compiled separately and could then be dynamically loaded into the classpath, located, and called by code from the core product.  This would allow us to have a single core product which would serve as a base which we would then add "customization modules" to fulfill the specific needs of customers which are too specific to be applied to the core product.

Does that make any sense?  Is there a standard approach to achieving this?  What sort of provisions does java have for loading code outside of a war file at runtime?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd answer this for the sake of anyone who runs across this.  Basically, you want to look at the plugin pattern.  If you search on that you should be able to find numerous variations of the pattern in your language of choice.